# Combobox disappears on disable in IE Extjs

Tags: internet-explorer, extjs, extjs3

I have a combo-box that I enable and disable based on certain condition.

```
 reportTypCombo: new Ext.form.ComboBox({
        id: 'reportTyp',
        name: 'reportTyp',
        valueField: 'value',
        displayField: 'value',
        typeAhead: true,
        fieldLabel: 'Type',
        allowBlank: false,
        forceSelection: true,
        triggerAction: 'all',
        store: ReportManager.Form.Stores.typeComboStore,
        mode: 'local',
        lastQuery: '',
        listeners: {
            expand: function(combo) {
                 .....
            },
            select: function(combo, record) {
                 ....
            },
            change:function(combo, newValue){
                 ....
            }
        }
```

when I call

```
reportTyp = form.findById('reportTyp');
reportTyp.setDisabled(false);
```

it disappears in IE.

Please guide me.

I tried the link http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?84452-Combobox-disappears-on-disable-in-IE-7 but could not solve it.

Comment: Which version of IE and ExtJS are you working with?

Comment: does `reportTyp.enable()` work?

Comment: My co-worker had a similar problem where upon hiding and disabling the combo, then showing it again, in IE 7/8 it would disappear except the first 17px would show up on the left side of it (the width of the trigger). A little playing in Firebug and I found that you could add the following to your CSS to "hack" it - might be worth a shot: 

    .x-form-field-trigger-wrap.x-item-disabled-ie {
        width: auto !important;
    }

Comment: have you tried doLayout, after your action?

Answer (score 1):

I have had this issue in the past and what solved it was removing the doctype from the page.
have you tires it?

Answer (score 0):

Use `Ext.getCmp('reportType').setDisabled(false);`

uset `ext.getCmp()` function to get needed component by id in `extjs`